# react-select show checked icon when item in menu is selected

Tags: reactjs, react-select

***Attempted to add an icon to an option in react-select. I only found the way to show the checked icon on every item in the menu, I added Icon to custom components but can't find the way to check if item is checked***

```
const customStyles = {

  option: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row-reverse",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    padding: "1rem",
    fontSize: "1.2rem",
    color: "#333333",
    lineHeight: "2rem",
    fontWeight: 600,
    padding: "1.2rem",
    borderRadius: "calc(0.8rem * 1.5)",
    cursor: "pointer",
    backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? "#16161a0f" : null,
    ":active": {
      backgroundColor: "#16161a0f",
    },
    ":hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#16161a0f",
    },
  }),
};

    const ReactSelect = ({ isMulti, options, value, onChange, inputRef, name }) => {
      const { Option } = components;
      const IconOption = (props) => (
        <Option {...props}>
          <CheckIconSC />
          {props.data.label}
        </Option>
      );
      return (
        <>
          <Select
            isClearable={false}
            isMulti={isMulti}
            styles={customStyles}
            options={options}
            placeholder={"Select one option"}
            components={{
              IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
              Option: IconOption,
            }}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
            inputRef={inputRef}
            name={name}
          />
        </>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
const IconOption = (props) => (
        <Option {...props}>
         {props.data.label}
         {props.isSelected && <CheckIconSC />}
        </Option>
      );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).